# Properly traverse an XmlSchema object

Tags: c#, xsd

I'm trying to extract data from an XmlSchema object generated from a DataSet I have with several tables. The XmlSchema in my below example will export as a full correct schema, but I have no idea how to traverse it.  There's only one Item and the Elements is always empty.  How do I get to the table and column elements in an XmlSchema object?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml.Schema;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DataTable table1 = new DataTable("patients");
        table1.Columns.Add("name");
        table1.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        table1.Rows.Add("sam", 1);
        table1.Rows.Add("mark", 2);

        DataTable table2 = new DataTable("medications");
        table2.Columns.Add("id", typeof(int));
        table2.Columns.Add("medication");
        table2.Rows.Add(1, "atenolol");
        table2.Rows.Add(2, "amoxicillin");

        DataSet set = new DataSet("office");
        set.Tables.Add(table1);
        set.Tables.Add(table2);

        using (var reader = new StringReader(set.GetXmlSchema()))
        using (var writer = new StringWriter()) 
        {
            var schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, (sender, args) => { });
            schema.Write(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine(schema.Elements.Values.Count);
            Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());
        }

        //Console.WriteLine(set.GetXmlSchema());
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do with reader and writer.  GetXmlSchema() should give you what you're looking for, no need for the rest of the code.

Comment: Sorry let me rephrase it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it works this way, but this proves that your schema object is filled properly:

```
string s = set.GetXmlSchema();
using (TextReader w = new StringReader(s)) {

    XmlSchema x = XmlSchema.Read(w, null);
    XmlSchemaElement e = (XmlSchemaElement)x.Items[0];
    XmlSchemaComplexType t = (XmlSchemaComplexType)e.SchemaType;
    XmlSchemaChoice c = (XmlSchemaChoice)t.Particle;
    XmlSchemaElement e2 = (XmlSchemaElement)c.Items[0];
    Console.WriteLine(e2.Name);
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, must have missed it while googling. What Microsoft page did you find that buried in?

Comment: I didn't, I found it while debugging.  Thanks for marking as answer.  Feel free to upvote as well ;)